# Module parse failed: Assigning to rvalue error with React&Express Firebase project, how to fix?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, express, runtime-error

I have no idea what to do about this error:

```
Failed to compile.
[1] 
[1] ./node_modules/@firebase/util/dist/cjs/src/constants.js
[1] Module parse failed: Assigning to rvalue (1:4)
[1] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
[1] | -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

What is it telling me? What do I do to fix it?
My app is running on Firebase, with a React front-end and Express back-end.